# Ubuntu OS installation error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

So I'm trying to switch from Windows to Ubuntu, creating the USB was done correctly (for more info I used rufus and fat32 in my 4gb USB) but whenever I boot from the USB I get a grub rescue error: symbol 'grub_calloc' not found.
I have tried every possible solution but still nothing, I ask for help even if you just give me the reason and thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your system meet minimum requirements: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  and did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM  ?

Comment: I suggest that you start over and follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you still need help you can reference the tutorial when asking. Also include details like the version and flavour of Ubuntu you are trying to install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Please provide the exact name of the Ubuntu ISO you downloaded (e.g. `ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso`) and the exact version of Rufus you used (e.g. Rufus 3.19) as knowing this information can be critical to being able to help you.